# jQuery multiple clicks, wait until user stops clicking

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a plus button to increase the number in a text field. When the text field value changes a `#updateCartButton` is triggered which updates the form through some other ajax/php code.

The problem I'm having is clicking 5 times on the plus button in rapid session also triggers `#updateCartButton` 5 times. I want `#updateCartButton` to be triggered once the user stops clicking the plus button, maybe after 500ms or something.

I tried to solve it `setTimeout`, like this, but it doesn't solve the problem:

```
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#updateCartButton').trigger('click'); // trigger update button
  }, 500);
```

Is there a simple solution to this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.plus').on('click', function() {
    var oldVal = $('input').val();
    var newVal = (parseInt($('input').val(),10) + 1);
    
    $('input').val(newVal);
    $('#updateCartButton').trigger('click'); // trigger update button
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="plus">+</button>
<input type="text" value="1">
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to only call the update on the last click by using `clearTimeout` to reset the timeout on all previous clicks.

```js
$(function() {
  var clickTimeout;

  $('.plus').on('click', function() {
    clearTimeout(clickTimeout);

    var oldVal = $('input').val();
    var newVal = (parseInt($('input').val(),10) + 1);

    $('input').val(newVal);

    clickTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#output').text($('input').val()); // replace with your update code
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="plus">+</button>
<input type="text" value="1">
<div>Updates on last click: <span id="output">1</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a variable that contains the timeout. If you want to override it, just call `clearTimeout();`:

```
$(function() {
var timeout;

  $('.plus').on('click', function() {
    var oldVal = $('input').val();
    var newVal = (parseInt($('input').val(),10) + 1);

    $('input[type="text"]').val(newVal);

    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      $('#updateCartButton').trigger('click'); // trigger update button
    }, 500);
  });

   $('#updateCartButton').click(function() {
        $('body').append('delayed button clicked <br/>')
   });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmsm7efq/1/)